# Decoding a Huffman AC table from JpegSnoop

Tags: image, metadata, jpeg, huffman-code

I have an AC Huffman table generated as follows:

```
Destination ID = 1
  Class = 1 (AC Table)
    Codes of length 01 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 02 bits (002 total): 00 01 
    Codes of length 03 bits (001 total): 02 
    Codes of length 04 bits (002 total): 03 11 
    Codes of length 05 bits (004 total): 04 05 21 31 
    Codes of length 06 bits (004 total): 06 12 41 51 
    Codes of length 07 bits (003 total): 07 61 71 
    Codes of length 08 bits (004 total): 13 22 32 81 
    Codes of length 09 bits (007 total): 08 14 42 91 A1 B1 C1 
    Codes of length 10 bits (005 total): 09 23 33 52 F0 
    Codes of length 11 bits (004 total): 15 62 72 D1 
    Codes of length 12 bits (004 total): 0A 16 24 34 
    Codes of length 13 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 14 bits (001 total): E1 
    Codes of length 15 bits (002 total): 25 F1 
    Codes of length 16 bits (119 total): 17 18 19 1A 26 27 28 29 2A 35 36 37 38 39 3A 43 
                                         44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 63 
                                         64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 82 
                                         83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
                                         9A A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 
                                         B8 B9 BA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA D2 D3 D4 D5 
                                         D6 D7 D8 D9 DA E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA F2 F3 
                                         F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA 
    Total number of codes: 162
```

I need to find the *Mincode*, *Maxcode* and *Valptr* values from this table. Apparently the decode procedure is not similar to the one of the DC table.

The following answer explains the retrieval of these values from a DC table:

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72786218/decoding-a-jpeg-huffman-table)

Answer (score 0):

The generation of those tables and the Huffman decoding of the eight-bit value is exactly the same for AC and DC coefficients. What you *do* with the resulting eight-bit values is different.

Comment: I am working on writing a code to solve this